# Google unified messaging platform SDK implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, admob

I am wondering how I can make the form show in my iOS App https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/ios/quick-start.

I am using Xcode vs 11.6 and exported the game from Godot game engine.

I have changed the `GADApplicationIdentifier` in my `info.plist` and I don't get any errors in my code it just doesn't show the form when I run the game. I live in Europe. Any help is appreciated.

This is my current code:

```
#include <UserMessagingPlatform/UserMessagingPlatform.h>
#import "ViewController1.h"
#include <UserMessagingPlatform/UserMessagingPlatform.h>

@interface ViewController1 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController1
- (void)start {
    // Create a UMPRequestParameters object.
    UMPRequestParameters *parameters = [[UMPRequestParameters alloc] init];
    // Set tag for under age of consent. Here @NO means users are not under age.
    parameters.tagForUnderAgeOfConsent = @NO;

    // Request an update to the consent information.
    [UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance
        requestConsentInfoUpdateWithParameters:parameters
                             completionHandler:^(NSError *_Nullable error) {
                               if (error) {
                                 // Handle the error.
                               } else {
                                 // The consent information state was updated.
                                 // You are now ready to check if a form is
                                 // available.
                                UMPFormStatus formStatus =
                                    UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance
                                           .formStatus;
                                if (formStatus == UMPFormStatusAvailable) {
                                    [self loadForm];
                                   }
                               }
                             }];
    
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Create a UMPRequestParameters object.
    UMPRequestParameters *parameters = [[UMPRequestParameters alloc] init];
    // Set tag for under age of consent. Here @NO means users are not under age.
    parameters.tagForUnderAgeOfConsent = @NO;

    // Request an update to the consent information.
    [UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance
        requestConsentInfoUpdateWithParameters:parameters
                             completionHandler:^(NSError *_Nullable error) {
                               if (error) {
                                 // Handle the error.
                               } else {
                                 // The consent information state was updated.
                                 // You are now ready to check if a form is
                                 // available.
                                UMPFormStatus formStatus =
                                    UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance
                                           .formStatus;
                                if (formStatus == UMPFormStatusAvailable) {
                                    [self loadForm];
                                   }
                               }
                             }];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)loadForm {
[UMPConsentForm loadWithCompletionHandler:^(UMPConsentForm *form,
                                            NSError *loadError) {
  if (loadError) {
    // Handle the error.
  } else {
    // Present the form. You can also hold on to the reference to present
    // later.
    if (UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus ==
        UMPConsentStatusRequired) {
      [form
          presentFromViewController:self
                  completionHandler:^(NSError *_Nullable dismissError) {
                    if (UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus ==
                        UMPConsentStatusObtained) {
                      // App can start requesting ads.
                    }

                  }];
    } else {
      // Keep the form available for changes to user consent.
    }
  }
}];
}


@end
```

Comment: Hi cooldude22 - I never used either Godot (although it looks super cool, dude) nor admob, but some suggestions only ... maybe move the ```[super viewDidLoad]``` to be the first line in that message and also move the rest of the stuff now in ```viewDidLoad``` into ```viewWillAppear```. Even if that works it still requires a bit of polish but that is easy to try and I think you are trying to present a controller from another controller that is not yet visible which may be causing the trouble you are experiencing.

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding! I will try that now. How do I make the view controller visible. Because I have to make a new view controller because Godot already has one that you can’t change so I have to create a new class. But how would I go about to make that visible?

Comment: No you don't have to make it visible, it is more that the code you now have in the ```viewDidLoad``` message should be transferred to *I think* the ```viewDidAppear``` or ```viewWillAppear``` messages. Either will do for now, take the ```viewDidAppear``` which means your VC is visible and on screen.

Comment: Note what I suggest requires more or less no work on your side, just transfer what you have to a new message. I'll post as an answer, although I'm not sure it will solve it, but it is easy to try and I need more space to post it.

Comment: Have you figured out how it works to show the form? Since you haven't mentioned it in you question I've to ask if you have created the "Funding Choices" account and also added the `NSUserTrackingUsageDescription` in your `info.plist` as it is stated in the documentation you linked?

Comment: Yes I have made the account. I think the problem lies in godot and not Xcode

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Add a few `NSLog` to see what gets called.

try the following - just a stone into the bush, maybe it hits something ...

```
#include <UserMessagingPlatform/UserMessagingPlatform.h>
#import "ViewController1.h"
#include <UserMessagingPlatform/UserMessagingPlatform.h>

@interface ViewController1 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController1
- (void)start {
    // Create a UMPRequestParameters object.
    UMPRequestParameters *parameters = [[UMPRequestParameters alloc] init];
    // Set tag for under age of consent. Here @NO means users are not under age.
    parameters.tagForUnderAgeOfConsent = @NO;

    // Request an update to the consent information.
    [UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance
        requestConsentInfoUpdateWithParameters:parameters
                             completionHandler:^(NSError *_Nullable error) {
                               if (error) {
                                 // Handle the error.
                               } else {
                                 // The consent information state was updated.
                                 // You are now ready to check if a form is
                                 // available.
                                UMPFormStatus formStatus =
                                    UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance
                                           .formStatus;
                                if (formStatus == UMPFormStatusAvailable) {
                                    [self loadForm];
                                   }
                               }
                             }];
    
}

// Change this one
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


// Add this one
- ( void ) viewDidAppear:( BOOL ) animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // View controller is now visible and on screen, so request permission
    self.addMobStuff;
}

// Change / add this one
- ( void ) addMobStuff {
    NSLog( @"addMobStuff" );
    // Create a UMPRequestParameters object.
    UMPRequestParameters *parameters = [[UMPRequestParameters alloc] init];
    // Set tag for under age of consent. Here @NO means users are not under age.
    parameters.tagForUnderAgeOfConsent = @NO;

    // Request an update to the consent information.
    if ( ! UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance )
    {
        NSLog(@"No shared instance");
    }
    [UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance
        requestConsentInfoUpdateWithParameters:parameters
                             completionHandler:^(NSError *_Nullable error) {
                               if (error) {
                                 // Handle the error.
                                 NSLog(@"Some error %@", error);
                               } else {
                                 NSLog(@"Proceed to form ...");
                                 // The consent information state was updated.
                                 // You are now ready to check if a form is
                                 // available.
                                UMPFormStatus formStatus =
                                    UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance
                                           .formStatus;
                                if (formStatus == UMPFormStatusAvailable) {
                                    NSLog(@"Loading form ...");
                                    [self loadForm];
                                   }
                                 else {
                                    NSLog(@"Form status is not available");
                                 }
                               }
                             }];
}

- (void)loadForm {
[UMPConsentForm loadWithCompletionHandler:^(UMPConsentForm *form,
                                            NSError *loadError) {
  if (loadError) {
    // Handle the error.
    NSLog(@"Form error %@", error);
  } else {
    // Present the form. You can also hold on to the reference to present
    // later.
    if (UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus ==
        UMPConsentStatusRequired) {
      NSLog(@"Presenting form");
      [form
          presentFromViewController:self
                  completionHandler:^(NSError *_Nullable dismissError) {
                    if (UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus ==
                        UMPConsentStatusObtained) {
                      // App can start requesting ads.
                    }

                  }];
    } else {
      // Keep the form available for changes to user consent.
      NSLog(@"Changes");
    }
  }
}];
}


@end
```

note if this works it probably needs a bit more polish before it can be released into the world but hopefully at least the request form will be displayed ...

Comment: This did not work. Do you know how to show like a white image or something so I know if it's the code or my google funding choices that's wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure that my view controller code is called

Comment: Add a few ```NSLog``` to the code - see my latest edit, just an example, you can also add NSLog to taste.

Comment: Well then the problem is somewhere else, not with this code ...

Comment: I tried to but it at run at start but I got Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code error

Comment: I wish I could assist more but SO is mean to address really specific isues e.g. what is wrong with this code or please help with that, where this or that are really specific, bite sized code snippets.. Here we are not even sure where the problem is - maybe you should just google around a bit to find an example that takes you the next step at least.

Comment: well then thanks for the help. I'll look around for solutions.

Comment: Ok ... when you solve this one please post some comment here again or if you just manage to make that next step do the same at least I know you progressed and can maybe help with one of the later steps ...

Comment: May I add you on discord or is that too far ahahah. I'll keep you updated.